# Reinitializing a Javascript library from a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I need to enable and disable RTL on Swiper but [it hasn't rtl as Javascript option](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/3246), only as [HTML attribute](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/master/demos/350-rtl.html) by adding `dir="rtl"` on `swiper-container`.

So, as suggested by the library creator, I'm trying adding that attribute. When added it instantly places slides in reverse order (right to left) but it doesn't let scroll in that way, just only from left to right.

Here the code I'm using (check the callback `on: resize`)

```
$('.js-carousel').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);

  var carousel = new Swiper($(this), {
    slidesPerView: 2.2,
    spaceBetween: 22,
    grabCursor: true,
    speed: 550,

    // Free mode
    freeMode: true,
    freeModeMomentumRatio: 1,
    freeModeMomentumVelocityRatio: 1.5,
    freeModeMomentumBounceRatio: 1,
    freeModeMinimumVelocity: 0.02,
    freeModeSticky: false,

    // Touch Resistance
    resistanceRatio: 0.85,

    // Prevent blurry texts
    roundLengths: true,

    // Events
    on: {
      resize: function () {
        this.$el.attr("dir", "rtl"); // <== Here I add attribute on window resize
        this.rtl = true; // <== Here I set the rtl boolean
        this.update(); // <== Here I should reinitialize the carousel? This command seems not to work
      },
    }

});
```

Comment: From what I can tell, the update does work though. When I resize the window, the element moves to the right of the screen. What are you expecting to happen? Also, looking at the object, there *is* an `rtl` property which you can set by doing `this.rtl = true;` inside the event handler, although it's not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Hi @EternalHour I tried but it's the same, I updated the code if you want to check it

Comment: Still unsure of your expected behavior. The element moves to the right, are you expecting to be able to slide it to the right off the screen?